# PowerShell fomat.ps1xml not reachable

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, exchange-2010

I'm trying to load Exchange Management Shell and it gives me a big 'ol red error that says:

`Import-Module : There were errors in loading the format data file: Microsoft.PowerShell, , %APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Exchange\RemotePowerShell\DOMAINNAME.format.ps1xml : 



File skipped because of the following validation exception: File %APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Exchange\RemotePowerShell\DOMAINNAME.format.ps1xml cannot be loaded. 



The file %APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\ExchangeRemotePowerShell\DOMAINNAME\DOMAINNAME.format.ps1xml is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details...`

The %APPDATA% is stored on an external server on my network (that I can ping to without problems). I am missing a ton of PS cmdlets too, which I'm presuming are stored in '*.format.ps1xml'

I tried finding the directory in which format.ps1xml is supposed to reside on the external server and it's not even created.

Can someone tell me where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

It still asks me about running the script, but at least it gives me an option to run it.  Execution-Policy = RemoteSigned somhow didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the execution policy to RemoteSigned on the local computer.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```